# Where can find older versions of Apps?

Tags: applications

**Is is possible to download older versions of Android applications?**

Is there some kind of online archive for all versions of Android apps? Like how you can find older versions of some Windows app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The site [Freeware Lovers](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/apps) collects freeware Android apps and has old versions for many of the apps they host. (Also for BlackBerry, Symbian, and Palm OS.)

Answer (score 18):

Some alternative repositories, such as [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/), allow you to choose which version you want to download; all versions ever offered are in the [repository](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/).

For most other sites, including the Android Market, the latest version is all that is available.

Comment: They seem to keep only last 3 versions

Answer (score 13):

The safe and correct way to get an older version is contacting the developer.  Maybe they will just give it to you or maybe not - there is a reason why they updated it in the first place.  Most importantly they will want to know why and you won't get any hacked malware version as is possible from other sources.

Answer (score 8):

[APKMirror from "Android Police"](http://www.apkmirror.com)

You can find previous versions of some common apps installation files such as Google Play services, WhatsApp, and Google Play Store.

Note that what you may recall as different versions of the same app might be actually listed as two separate apps. For example, [Google Calendar](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/calendar/) and [Google Calendar (old)](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/calendar-old/) are listed separately.

Answer (score 6):

I found this site: [apkpure](https://apkpure.com/)

From about:

> APKPure.com is a website providing smartphones software downloads founded in 2014 by APKPure Team[...]
>
> [...]We offer one of the most comprehensive collections of Apps, Games, and history version list. All download works guarantee 100% no extra extension needed.[...]

Comment: I found [LeipzigMOVE (de.tafmobile.mobility.leipzigmove)](https://apkpure.com/leipzigmove-public-transport/de.tafmobile.mobility.leipzigmove) on apkpure, but not on apkmirror. Even older versions. (Can’t ensure integrity, though...)

Answer (score 0):

I have a tool that can do this [1]. However it is limited, in that you must
provide the version number. Here is example getting YouTube version 4123 (October 2014):

```
googleplay -a com.google.android.youtube -v 4123
```

I havent found a way to list the available versions, so you would need to find
the version number somewhere else.

1. https://github.com/89z/googleplay