# Where can I download a specific version of an app?

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can find older versions of Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/where-can-find-older-versions-of-apps)

I require certain versions of apps like `facebook`, `twitter` and `Temple Run` in order to perform research. I have already looked at `freewarelovers` but that doesn't give me options of downloading specific versions.

Comment: you can try [appzapk android apps apk](http://appzapk.com/).
They have all versions of apps.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be reaching out to developers of these apps.  Other alternatives would be unsafe.

Comment: Thought it's highly unlikely that A+ developers would actually respond.

Comment: ok, I can try asking them.. but thinking of that as my best bet makes me uneasy. :( thanks anyway