# How can I get old Android softwares?

Tags: google-play-store, sony-ericsson-live-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can find older versions of Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/where-can-find-older-versions-of-apps)

Sony LiveView -application dropped the support from the old Android versions -- some problems [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27666/cannot-establish-connection-with-liveview-with-h8800-android-device) -- and now I cannot use it. I want to get the old version of the Sony LiveView but it is not available in the market. It was replaced by the newest Android version. How can I get the old version of App thaw was later available in Android Market?