# Revert update of Gmail app

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to revert the latest update of the Gmail app for Android?

Comment: Yes, you can either uninstall the update or maybe even  [download older versions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/where-can-find-older-versions-of-apps)

Comment: For the future I recommend using an app like [AppMonster Pro Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro), which always makes a backup of each package you install/backup (and optionally auto-purges, to keep only a limited number of backups per app) -- so you always have some versions to revert to. As for now, see Andrew's answer below or follow ce4's link. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy to revert to individual previous versions, but you can revert easily to the stock version that came with your phone.

1. Find Gmail in "My Apps" in the Google Play Store
2. Tap <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>
3. Tap <kbd>OK</kbd> to uninstall updates and revert to original

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Revert to stock version, (as above)
 then go here via the mobe's web browser:
   http://www.apk4fun.com/history/901/
 or here
   http://gmail.en.uptodown.com/android/old
Find a previous version you want, download & install.
Make sure the phone settings allow install from non-GooglePlay locations.
 Actually all quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apps - Gmail then go down to to the AP settings. It opened up the play store and I had the option to uninstall updates. It went back to a fresh start, just log in and it seems to work fine but a slightly older format.