# How to revert Hangouts to Google Talk in Samsung S4

Tags: google, samsung, google-talk

I just updated my Android version to 4.3. However, Google Talk is replaced by Hangouts automatically. I don't like Hangouts, since I cannot see friends who are online/offline. I wish to revert to Google Talk. When I try to uninstall Hangouts, there is no uninstall option for me.

I am using a Samsung S4 smartphone. Does anyone know how to revert to Google Talk?

Comment: If you're comfortable sideloading apps rather than only getting them from the Play Store, this Question and its answers may be of help: [Where can find older versions of Apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14910)

Comment: Note, though, that you'll probably continually be pestered to update and it's likely that down the road the old Google Talk app just won't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hangout is the replacement to Google Talk. And on Hangout you CAN see people online. Go into Hangout, Click the + sign to have "New Hangout" (+ sign is on top right, or simply swipe from right to left), and all people with a green hangout sign are online people. All people with grey hangout are offline, but you can send them 'offline' messages so they can see it as soon as they are online.

Unfortunately this is only half the answer as I don't see a way to remove Hangout back to Google Talk. If anyone can add to this answer, please do.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't install *Hangouts* via Play Store, it was supplied by the update. In that case, there is no way to get the old Google Talk back.

An alternative would be installing a messenger app that supports GTalk and/or XMPP (XMPP is the protocol GTalk uses).

some messaging apps:

- [Xabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android&hl=de) is an open-source, fully configurable XMPP client
- [imo.im](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imo.android.imoim&hl=de) is closed-source and displays ads in the non-paid version
- [IM+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite) is closed-source